# Is it possible to keep an object hovering in front of the camera using vuforia in android?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm developing an app that needs a certain 3d object hovering in front of the user when he looks through the camera. Using vuforia I need to use an Image marker to place an object. Is it possible to do the placing without an image marker?

I also don't want to use Unity 3D as I'm developing a native Android app that has other functionalities too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the image target, use mid-air target in Vuforia. See *Placing Floating Content in your Environment* in this [article](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/ground-plane-guide.html) for the detailed explanation.

Comment: The article is about implementing this in Unity. How can we do this in native Android?

Comment: https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/samples download android sample and look for the ground plane. mid-air targets are based on the ground plane. You can look at the code, build and run the sample.

Comment: Thank you @Divyansh. That needs ARCore. I must find some other SDK now.

Comment: @tbfp yes, AR core is required.